# Best way to add MVC to a Web.api-project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an existing web.api-project that I need to add a mvc5 controller/view to.

I tried to add this by hand by adding bits and pieces of folders, references and config-stuff here and there in the project. Clearly i was not successful because when I try to view my cshtml-files the server just returns server errors. Now I want to start over in structured manner.

So, with a pure web.api-project at hand, how can I add mvc-support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an empty mvc application (with web api) and migrate the pure web api project to it. It shouldn't be much work to copy all the controllers and routes.

Comment: Thanks.I actually thought of that, but it seems kind of the wrong way around. I fear it's pretty timeconsuming since the web.api project is pretty large and custom structured but yeah: maybe that's the way to go. But you know, I only need 2 or 3 mvc's...and not tons of folders and config-stuf infecting my web.api base;) well thanks, I'll try it if nothings else is proposed. /Thomas

Answer (score 0):

To others who may face the same issue:

Folllowing Dzhenko's advice proved to be the right way to go.

1. Create an EMPTY asp-net project clicking support for both MVC and web.api in the second dialog using "new project".
2. Copy files from old solution to new.

I went about adding all the references again by hand (doing some cleaning up at the same time), but perhapse this can be automated and made even easier.